# Dealing with Asynchronous and Synchronous requests Retrofit 2 simultaneously

Tags: android, retrofit2, interceptor, okhttp

I am using Okhttp3 interceptor to refresh access token when the API returns an error response (The API I use is little weird and returns 200 for error responses as well, so I am unsure about the use of Authenticator). Here is my Interceptor code:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor {
@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
    String responseBodyString = response.body().string();
    Response returnResponse = response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(responseBody.contentType(), responseBodyString.getBytes())).build();
    if(responseBodyString.contains("error")) {
        DataDownloadManager.getInstance().downloadToken();
        LogUtils.LOGE("Interceptor", "DownloadManager called");
        Request newRequest = request.newBuilder().build();
        LogUtils.LOGE("Interceptor", "new request dispatched");
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
    else {
        LogUtils.LOGE("Interceptor", "Outside");
        return returnResponse;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my DataDownloadManager:

```
public final class DataDownloadManager {

...... 

public static DataDownloadManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DataDownloadManager();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void downloadToken() {
    try {
        AccessToken accessToken = client.geteTouchesAPI().getAccessToken(APIUtils.ACCOUNT_ID, APIUtils.ACCOUNT_KEY)
                .execute().body();
        AccountUtils.setAccessToken(MyApplication.getAppContext(), accessToken.getToken());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void downloadSessionList() {
    client.geteTouchesAPI().getSessionList(AccountUtils.getAccessToken(MyApplication.getAppContext()), APIUtils.EVENT_ID).enqueue(new Callback<List<SessionList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<SessionList>> call, Response<List<SessionList>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                for (SessionList sessionList : response.body()) {
                    LogUtils.LOGE(LOG_TAG, sessionList.getSessionId());
                    LogUtils.LOGE(LOG_TAG, sessionList.getSessionKey());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<SessionList>> call, Throwable t) {
            LogUtils.LOGE(LOG_TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my Logcat:

```
07-15 20:17:12.530 29634-29992/com.my.app E/Interceptor: Outside
07-15 20:17:12.533 29634-29992/com.my.app E/AccountUtils: 
Setting access token to: ....
07-15 20:17:12.534 29634-29992/com.my.app E/Interceptor: 
DownloadManager called
07-15 20:17:12.534 29634-29992/com.my.app E/Interceptor: new 
request dispatched
07-15 20:17:13.170 29634-29634/com.my.app 
E/DataDownloadManager: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 
BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

My initial call is `DataDownloadManager.getInstance().downloadSessionList()` and as seen in the logcat even after an error response, the request is not executed again. Instead, the initial failed response is returned resulting in the error as shown in the last line of logcat, which should not be the case. Since I am retrying the request on error, the only thing that should execute is on the `onResponse()` callback of the `downloadSessionList()`, instead `onFailure()` is executed and that too only once (where did my second request go?).

I suspect that this is a synchronization issue, but I am not able to figure out exactly where.

Comment: `Interceptor: Outside` indicates that the response body doesn't contain the string "error", so it won't retry.

Comment: @nasch It will retry and is retrying, the problem was that the `accesstoken` was `null` when there was no `accesstoken` for the first time and okhttp ignores null parameters and does not append them to the request. So, when I did `request.newBuilder().build()` it still retried the original request as expected with no accesstoken attached. So, I had to modify the url to attach the accesstoken to it and it worked.

Comment: How about posting and accepting an answer?